# Value Error: The truth value of a Series is ambigous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, datetime

Tengo un Dataframe como este:

```
        ORDERPRICE  ORDERDATE           PRODUCTCODE CUSTOMERNAME            CITY        COUNTRY
ORDERID                                 

10364   2317.44     1/6/2005 0:00       S32_2206    Marseille Mini Autos    Marseille   France
10116   1711.26     4/11/2003 0:00      S32_3207    Royale Belge            Charleroi   Belgium
10144   1637.20     8/13/2003 0:00      S32_4289    Royale Belge            Charleroi   Belgium
```

El objetivo, es crear una lista de aquellos años (sin repetir) por los que existe una orden a Francia. He hecho lo siguiente:

```
# Convertimos el objeto ORDERTIME a datetime y creamos la columna date

df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['ORDERDATE'])

# Extraemos el año y creamos una columna que se llama `year`

df['year'] = df['date'].apply(lambda datetime: datetime.year)

# Buscamos qué años tienen una orden con pais FRANCIA

years = []
anys = df['year']

for year in anys:
#Ponemos la condición que el pais sea Francia y que el año no este ya en la lista creada
    if (df.COUNTRY == 'France') and (year not in years):
        #Lo añadimos a la lista
        years.append(df.year)

print(years)
```

Sin embargo, me da el siguiente error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-201-78293cd9c481> in <module>
     11 
     12 for year in anys:
---> 13     if (df.COUNTRY == 'France') and (year not in years):
     14         years.append(df.year)
     15 

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in __nonzero__(self)
   1476 
   1477     def __nonzero__(self):
-> 1478         raise ValueError(
   1479             f"The truth value of a {type(self).__name__} is ambiguous. "
   1480             "Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()."

ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

No entiendo porqué me da el error. He comprovado los tipos de las variables y years está definida como una lista. Alguna idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La condición siguiente está mal expresada:

```
if (df.COUNTRY == 'France') and (year not in years):
```

Debido a que `df.COUNTRY == 'France'` lo que te devuelve es una serie de booleanos, tantos como filas tenga `df`, con `True` en los lugares en que el pais sea "France" y `False` en los que no. En cambio `year not in years` te da un solo booleano. Para hacer la operación `and` entre ambos resultados, Python necesita convertir a un solo booleano el resultado de `df.COUNTRY = 'France'` y no sabe cómo, ya que  lo que tiene es una columna de booleanos en vez de uno solo (a eso se refiere con lo de que *"el valor booleano de una Serie es ambiguo"*)

Por otro lado la expresión no tiene demasiado sentido, tal como está escrita. Supongo que `year` que querrías mirar si está o no en `years` sería el de las filas en que haya aparecido "France".

Lo más parecido (sintácticamente) a lo que pretendías hacer, implica iterar por las filas del dataframe:

```
years = []

for idx, fila in df.iterrows():
  if fila.COUNTRY=="France" and fila.year not in years:
    years.append(fila.year)
```

Pero esta solución es muy ineficiente (especialmente para un número de filas grandes) por dos razones:

- No se recomienda iterar por filas siempre que se pueda evitar. La iteración es un bucle python lento. En su lugar suele haber soluciones usando primitivas pandas "vectorizadas" mucho más rápidas
- Comprobar si el año está o no en la lista `years` va requiriendo más y más tiempo a medida que la lista `years` tiene más elementos.

### Solución más adecuada

Una solución mucho más simple y eficiente es filtrar las filas de tu tabla para tomar sólo aquellas en las que el pais sea "France", para después aplicar la operación `.unique()` sobre la columna `year`, y obtener así la lista de años sin repeticiones. O sea:

```
years = df[df.COUNTRY=="France"].year.unique().tolist()
```

Sobre los datos de ejemplo que suministras, la operación anterior produce la lista `[2005]`

Comment: Muchas gracias por esta magnífica respuesta!